# Fine-tune SentenceTransformer/SBERT for Extractive Text Summarization

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, summarization, sentence-transformers, fine-tuning

Newbie here on NLP.

I want to build extractive text summarization, try to read this https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train-sentence-transformers, I think there is a way to fine-tune the model with my own dataset (data, and language), in case 2 like this `Case 2: The example is a pair of positive (similar) sentences without a label. For example, pairs of paraphrases, pairs of full texts and their summaries` but there is no tutorial on it. Want to try but all tutorial use labels.

Or I want to fine-tune the embedding on `Sentence-bert` but didn't find how to do it too. I think we can fine-tune the embedding and get the similarity of all sentences in the text.

Try on BERT but get stuck cause the tutorial is obsolete.

I was just lost and confused. Is anybody here who ever tries or knows and can give me advice or some tutorial code?